# SQL Server: Named Pipes error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I have Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Express installed on a VM.

I am getting the following error when I click on the run button on Visual Studio:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Code In Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database = Sample2; integrated security=SSPI"); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblemployee", con); con.Open(); 
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
GridView1.DataSource = rdr; 
GridView1.DataBind(); 
con.Close();
```

Comment: Clearly, the cause of error is that you are trying to connect to a SQL Server that cannot be reached. You can test wither the server is reachable by connecting to it through SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Please. Clearly your question , Where get this error ?

Comment: @Kilanny: Yes I can connect it using SQL Management Studio. Visual Studio and SQL are on the same machine.

Comment: @Ahmed Galal: When I click on the run button on Visual Studio.

Comment: 'public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database = Sample2; integrated security=SSPI");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblemployee", con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close(); 



        }'

Comment: I have created a SqlConnection

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database = Sample2; integrated security=SSPI"); =============================Then when I try to open con.open(); I am getting the error at this stage

Comment: Try replacing `integrated security=SSPI` with `integrated security=True`

Comment: in your connection string try replacing "database = Sample2" with "initial catalog = Sample2"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has marked the question "{CLOSED}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **default**, the SQL Server **Express** is installed as a **named instance** called `SQLEXPRESS`. So unless you've specifically changed anything during installation, you should be able to connect to it using this connection string:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Sample2;integrated security=SSPI"
```

Comment: It works. But it needs two backslashes instead of one. Took me some time to work out :-) Thank you.

Comment: @user3186277 That is from c# string escaping, if you add a `@` to the front of the string you can do it with a single slash. That is called using a "[Verbatim String Literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)"